# Путь к папкам css и js в Django проекте

Tags: python, django

Подскажите в какую папку static нужно класть и соответственно подключать *.css, .js* файлы?
Не могу никак подгрузить с хостинга файлы стилей, хоть и на локалке все работает норм

**Дерево папок на хостинге:**
[image: дерево папок на хостинге]

Сам статический файл подключаю так:

```
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

STATIC_ROOT - это директория куда будет собрана статика при раскатке проекта на проде.

Статика из приложений подхватится сама, я же рекомендую строить дерево каталогов статики в приложениях также как и для шаблонов.

Comment: еще пришлось запустить >python3 manage.py collectstatic
спасибо за помощь)